# OpenStack -keyStone: Does it provide encrypted login?

Tags: encryption, authentication, openstack, keystone

Its there anyway I can supply encrypted password during logging in to OpenStack Keystone ?
Does it have any tool for encryption ?

Comment: Any one ? 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with encrypted passwords?

Comment: If you host keystone APIs on secure HTTP (i.e. https://...) then all the authentication traffic is encrypted.

Comment: @Roman Bodnarchuk : Actually I have to login to openstack, by supplying encrypted credentials